# No route matches error for spec post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a post method in scorecard controller which take event id as params and create a score card for that event. When I am trying to send to post request with event id I am getting no routes matches for action empty_scorecard error.
here is Rspec code

```
   describe "POST empty_scorecard" do
    it "should create empty scorecard for two team event" do
      event = Event.first
      post :empty_scorecard, :event_id => event.id
    end
  end
```

here is routes for controller action

match '/scorecards/event/:event_id/empty_scorecard', :to => "scorecards#empty_scorecard", :method => :post

Comment: What is your controller `classname`?

Comment: You have to define routes through render or using get method first.